# CSS3 Drop-down menu fake JS issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to do a **dropdown** menu stylised with **Jquery** and **css3**.
I did the job and it's exactly what i want.
The only problem is that it's a trick with Jquery.

I want to **hide/show a div** when i click on one of my menu button.
The problem is that it does not do the job.
But it work without the trick.

Here the code working:

https://jsfiddle.net/74ca3epv/2/

You can see this is working, but

> remove the `display:none` from the `.styledSelect`

and you see that the show/hide div doesnt work anymore.
I hope you can understand what i mean.
All comments are welcome :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make changes here:

```
$listItems.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        //alert($(this).attr('rel'));

        if($(this).attr("rel")=="reservation1"){
                $("#information").hide();
                $("#reservation").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("rel")=="information1"){
                $("#reservation").hide();
                $("#information").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("rel")=="choose1"){
                $("#reservation").hide();
                $("#information").hide();
            }

        /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
    });
```

Check [Fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/74ca3epv/6/)